# Tools and techniques for diagnosing heating problems

Tags: 13.04, overheating

I've just installed ubuntu 13.04 on a dell M6700. The laptop becomes too hot to keep on your lap after short usage.

What are the best tools I can use to find out what the problem is and solve the issue?

Comment: Did you install the proprietary drivers for your graphics card? What GPU do you have in there? As suggested in the answer below this can significantly improve power consumption. Please provide the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(graphics|vga)"` to identify the hardware. Also: is it an Optimus enabled machine or does it only feature a discrete graphics card?

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
 Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:053f]
 Kernel driver in use: i915
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK104GLM [Quadro K3000M] [10de:11be] (rev a1)
 Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:153f]
 Kernel driver in use: nvidia
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corp Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0082] (rev 34)

Comment: @gertvdijk see comments in Barafu's answer

Comment: Well, your question seems answered now, but please **edit** your question next time. Comments are not fit for the information you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nvidia Quadro is guilty. You must install proprietary drivers and after that read more on tuning your video card for lower power consumption. Without it it is just in gaming mode - eats battery, produces heat. 
Does it have Nvidia Optimus technology? If yes, you have to tweak it too, otherwise you have 2 video cards working simultaneous.
Offtopic: Man, some cars are cheaper than your notebook.

Comment: Ok... I had tried installing nvidia-current, but it said the card wsnt detected.

Comment: How do I check if it has Optimus

Comment: Haha... yeah, I was helping someone out with some programming stuff, and he gifted it to me.

Comment: Search for a table which would say what version of NVIDIA drivers go for your card. About Optimus: read forums a lot, because making it work is an epic question.

Comment: Thanks, using nvidia-313-updates, /usr/share/doc/nvidia-313-updates/README.txt.gz says my card is supported. Will reboot and hope it improves.

Comment: Not sure if it's configured properly, but running 'sudo nvidia-xconfig --query-gpu-info' seemed to give me /dev/nvidiactl etc, not sure if that means that optimus is enabled though... will look more into it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run powertop to investigate where energy is used most

Also install tlp as follows
`sudo apt-get install tlp`

or 
install the package by hand: https://launchpad.net/~linrunner/+archive/tlp